# vuejs webpack + express + passport not working in PRODUCTION mode

Tags: express, vuejs2, passport-google-oauth2

I am completely new to vuejs

I am working on a MEVN app. I setup a vuejs project with vue-cli , which runs on `localhost:8080` , and an express server which runs on `localhost:3000`.
to send all the requests to my express server, I added proxy in vue's config/index.js which works perfectly.
Now i added passport google oauth in my app.
in server.js file i added

```
app.get('/auth/google',
passport.authenticate('google', {session : false, scope: ['openid email profile'],accessType: 'offline',prompt: 'consent'}))
```

and its callback route also

and in my vuejs code i added

```
<a href="/auth/google">Login with Google</a>
```

on clicking Login with Google my app works perfectly in development mode but in PRODUCTION mode when i click Login instead of going to google consent screen for login it goes to `<app-url>/auth/google` with a blank page

please help me with this..

**NOTE :**
for production mode i did npm run build and then served the static file in server.js file (express) , and also used connect-history-api-fallback

**UPDATE  :**
well `connect-history-api-fallback` was the problem but removing it results in  broken vuejs routes as m using them in `history mode`
now what to do ?

Comment: update your google-app, seems like you have callback setup to localhost

Comment: @2oppin thanks for ur response, i updated my question ,

i updated my google-app but then also i was getting this error.. and when i tried in localhost the error was same

basically when i run my app with client on other localhost:8080 and server on localhost:3000 it works perfectly.. but when i bundle the client and bring it to server.js (by serving the static 'dist' folder) i.e now my whole app npw runs on localhost:3000 it redirects to localhost:3000/auth/google with a blank page

Comment: and it doesnt even goes to google consent screen for signing up the user. it just stays there. so that callback part i guess doesn't get triggered

Comment: what  callback uri you have for your application, there:
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/
same place where you get your clientID and secret, you should fill valid (your production) uri

Comment: @2oppin yes i filled valid uri there but it isn't working.

Comment: ok, so you updated post, and now you have valid redirect to your (<app-url>), instead of local?
Now for the "blank page", it can be anything, you should debug it step-by step, by adding log, outputs, what is in console output? also blank, no errors?

Comment: @2oppin yes console is blank, and i tried to debug by adding logs , but log inside app.get('/auth/google') isn't logging anything , that means <a href='/auth/google'> is not falling in that route i guess....

Comment: well , @2oppin ,  its working when i remove `connect-history-api-fallback` but then my other vuejs routes fails.. (cannot GET /home)

Comment: is there any reason why you disabled connect-history-api-fallback? or blind guess?

Comment: that was a blind guess. but my app can't work without connect-history-api-fallback so i have to find some other way.

Comment: @2oppin well rearranging server.js code did the trick. Thanks for your quick responses mate..

Comment: glad you managed to solve issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well just re-arranging my server.js did the trick

moved app.use(history()) below app.get('auth/google') and it worked